# How do I count occurrences by day in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by

Newbie SQL question here -->

I've got an Occurrences table that contains a row for each time a user did something.  A user can do the thing multiple times per day.  It looks like this:

```
Date      Username
------    --------
1/1/9     User1
1/1/9     User1
1/1/9     User2
1/2/9     User1
1/2/9     User3
1/3/9     User1
1/3/9     User1
1/3/9     User1
1/3/9     User2
1/3/9     User3
```

I want a query to simply return the Username and the quantity (count) of unique days they appear.  For the above data set, the result I'm looking for would be:

```
Username    UniqueDaysAppeared
--------    ------------------
User1       3
User2       2
User3       2
```

I keep getting screwed up because my query is returning not the count of *unique* days per user but rather the number of occurrences of the user overall.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
SELECT Username, COUNT(DISTINCT(Date)) AS UniqueDaysAppeared
FROM Occurrences
GROUP BY Username
```

Comment: As they say in those Staples commercials, "That was easy!"  In all of my attempts I'd omitted the DISTINCT from the COUNT aggregate.  Thank you.

Comment: And as Tommy Cooper would say "Just like that!" :)